# How is "огурец" used here?

Tags: грамматика, творительный-падеж

Каждый  коротышка  был  ростом  с  небольшой
огурец.

I am translating it as every small person was of the size of small cucumber?

I am confused about the case, why is cucumber in accusative or nominative and why use с небольшой?

Comment: Was the *height* of small cucumber.

Comment: Nominative can never be used with prepositions, so it's an accusative.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1** This is one of adjectival constructions in Russian to denote likeness in terms of measures.

> **размером с** горошину  `as small as a pea`
>   **ростом с** мизинец `as short as a pinkie`
>   **весом с** пудовую гирю  `as heavy as a 16 kg weight`
>   рептилия **длиной с** автобус  `a reptile as long as a bus`
>   **глубиной с** Марианскую впадину  `as deep as Mariana Trench`
>   **толщиной с** бревно  `as thick as a log`
>   **шириной с** футбольное поле `as wide as a football field`

In these the preposition **C** governs Accusative case because it implies a question **c кого? с что?**

An approximation of literal translation would be
**`OF THE`**`size/length/width/height/depth etc.`**`OF`**`...`
but a more idiomatic one is
**`AS`**`big/small/long/short/high/low/deep etc.`**`AS`**`...`

A word denoting a type of dimension or quality (**размером**, **высотой**, **шириной**, **длиной** etc) can be omitted if it's clear from the context

> помидор <strike>размером</strike> с горошину
>   кулак <strike>величиной</strike> с пудовую гирю
>   змеи <strike>толщиной</strike> с бревно
>   сосиски <strike>длиной</strike> с мизинец

**2** Instead of **небольшой** one can use **маленький** as well. But in this context these words differ in their register. **Маленький** could be perceived as belonging to a primitive language, like that of children and  poorly educated speakers.

Comment: could not leave the comment, to short

Comment: Where does this qualification of "маленький" come from? It isn't style-primitive in any sense, and isn't a semantical analogue of "небольшой". How about that trend in the 19th c. Russian literature, "маленькие люди"?

Granted, it's used slightly differently that "малый", tending to more unofficial vs. official use (like, in documents: "малая трещина", "малые затраты"). But that's that.

Comment: it comes from my experience as a native speaker, everything is context dependent, in this particular context i consider my qualification accurate, it's not possible to foresee all potential types of context, also **малый** and **маленький** are quite different in their use and mixing them would be misleading, however i did add a reservation to my answer regarding context, if there's a need for authoritative source, [Wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/небольшой) recognizes **небольшой**, **малый** and **маленький** as synonyms

Comment: Well, I *am* a native speaker, and this qualification is totally new to me. I wouldn't write "маленькие затраты" in the official document vs. "малые затраты", but does the word really "tend to be perceived as belonging to primitive [?] language [style?]"??

(Also: is Wiktionary an authoritative source now? Like: is it now refereed, quality-checked, etc.? Last time I looked, wiki-sources weren't recognised as authoritative even in the wiki-context).

Comment: indeed we're all native speakers here and everyone's experience is different, i'm not in the mood for debates and don't come here in search for any, if you strongly disagree, you have the opportunity to post an alternative answer, have a great day

Comment: I don't need "debates", just -- if you please -- some substantiation of your (rather extreme) statement on the adjective. Is it your personal experience, then?

Comment: if i'm to reiterate my earlier reply, yes it is... in adult non-fiction literature *маленький* is rarely used to denote a size, and rightfully so as it sounds childish, being supplemented with *небольшой*, overall i think the topic of differentiation between these two words in usage is complex and multi-faceted, enough to be a subject of a paper in  linguistics

Answer (score 2):

"Небольшой" is perceived as slightly bigger than "маленький", but not yet so big as "big". Think "medium or just a tad bigger".

And "коротышка", being the quasi-race name, would be better translated as, e.g., "shortling".

Answer (score 0):

Each shorty was *as tall as* a small (standing) cucumber.